# Check the IIS virtual path in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, virtual-path

I am trying to encrypt some sections of the **web.config** file of one of my applications by using **RSA encryption** at **user level**.

So I followed all the steps listed in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and I succesfully created the provider and granted access to my application. However, I have some problems in specifying the virtual path for my application.

I run **IIS 7.5** in a **Windows Server 2008 R2**. My application is called **www.testsite.com** and its ID is **4**.

The **aspnet_regiis** tool is placed in the **Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]** folder:

Therefore in order to encrypt the `connectionStrings` section I run the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe connectionStrings -app "[Application Path]" -prov "myRSAProvider"
```

I tried as **[Application Path]**, the followings:

- /W3SVC/4
- /W3SVC/4/root
- /W3SVC/4/root/www.testsite.com
- /www.testsite.com

And I always receive the error

> The configuration for virtual path '[Application Path]' and site
>   'Default Web Site' cannot be opened.
>
> Failed to map the path '[Application Path]'. Failed!

I tried to browse many resources on the web but this IIS virtual path specification is not extensively covered. In IIS6 I could get it by running **aspet_regiis -lk** but this command does not work anymore in IIS 7.5. May somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

You may be having two issues.

1. At the end of your command statement specify your **site** with the command *-site "4"*   Also note that instead of the #4 you could write in your site name instead. e.g. *-site "www.testsite.com"*

   `aspnet_regiis -pe connectionStrings -app "[Application Path]" -prov "myRSAProvider" -site "4"`
2. It is also very important that you **run the command prompt as Administrator**.

I had the same error you had running IIS 7.5 in a Windows Server 2008 R2 and this is what helped me.